# Context based termination of long running loop in a go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm implementing a feature where I need to read files from a directory, parse and export them to a REST service at a regular interval. As part of the same I would like to gracefully handle the program termination (SIGKILL, SIGQUIT etc).
Towards the same I would like to know how to implement Context based cancellation of process.

For executing the flow in regular interval I'm using gocron.

### cmd/scheduler.go

```
func scheduleTask(){
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    s := gocron.NewScheduler()
    s.Every(10).Minutes().Do(processTask, ctx)
    s.RunAll()  // run immediate
    <-s.Start() // schedule
    for {
        select {
        case <-(ctx).Done():
            fmt.Print("context done")
            s.Remove(processTask)
            s.Clear()
            cancel()
        default:
        }
    }
}   
func processTask(ctx *context.Context){
  task.Export(ctx)
}
```

### task/export.go

```
func Export(ctx *context.Context){
   pendingFiles, err := filepath.Glob("/tmp/pending/" + "*_task.json")
   //error handling
   //as there can be 100s of files, I would like to break the loop when context.Done() to return asap & clean up the resources here as well
   for _, fileName := range pendingFiles {

    exportItem(fileName string)
   }
}

func exportItem(fileName string){
    data, err := ReadFile(fileName)  //not shown here for brevity
    //err handling
    err = postHTTPData(string(data)) //not shown for brevity
    //err handling
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://blog.golang.org/context).

Comment: Thanks. I am having confusion in structuring the code for the 'for loop" where i'm going over the files (Export()). Should the loop be part of default case:  for {
  select {
  case <-(ctx).Done():

  default:
    // loop & process files here??
  }
 }

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: Should the loop be inside the default: case in Export()- no. Since it sounds like you want to check for and respond to cancellation before processing each individual file in pendingFiles, put the select{} block inside the for range pendingFiles, and have exportItem as the default case. Also, perhaps create a derivative context using WithTimeout in postHTTPData.

Comment: Your `for{select{}}` is just a tight loop with the emtpy default; it'll eat as much CPU as it can get. If you're just waiting on the `ctx.Done()`, there's no reason to have the `for` *or* the `select`; you'd get the same behavior more efficiently with `<-ctx.Done()` by itself.

Comment: Thanks. it worked in terms of my execution is getting stopped as expected. However my log statements in the <-ctx.Done() case are not being printed to file like other log statements in code.

Answer (score 2):

For the process management, I think the other component is the actual handling of [signals](https://gobyexample.com/signals), and managing the context from those signals.

I'm not sure of the specifics of go-cron ([they have an example showing some of these concepts on their github](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/cron#synopsis)) but in general I think that the steps involved are:

- Registration of os signals handler
- Waiting to receive a signal
- Canceling top level context in response to a signal

Example:

```
sigCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
defer close(sigCh)
signal.Notify(sigCh, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGQUIT, syscall.SIGINT)
<-sigCh
cancel()
```

I'm not sure how this will look in the context of go-cron, but the context that the signal handling code cancels should be a parent of the context that the task and job is given.

Comment: I didnt try this as of now as the context worked. I'll try this as well as sugegsted.

Answer (score 1):

Worked this out myself just now. I've always felt the blog post on contexts was A LOT of material to try and understand so a simpler demonstration would be nice.

There are many scenarios you may encounter. Each one is different and will require adaptation. Here's one example:

Say you have a channel that could run for an indeterminate amount of time.

```
indeterminateChannel := make(chan string)
for s := range indeterminateChannel{
   fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Your producer might look something like:

```
for {
  indeterminateChannel <- "Terry"
}
```

We don't control the producer, so we need someway to cut out of your print loop if the producer exceeds your time limit.

```
indeterminateChannel := make(chan string)

// Close the channel when our code exits so OUR for loop no longer occupies
// resources and the goroutine exits.
// The producer will have a problem, but we don't care about their problems.
// In this instance.
defer close(indeterminateChannel)

// we wait for this context to time out below the goroutine.
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), time.Minute*1)
defer cancel()

go func() {
 for s := range indeterminateChannel{
   fmt.Println(s)
 }
}()

<- ctx.Done // wait for the context to terminate based on a timeout.
```

You can also check `ctx.Err` to see if the context exited due to a timeout or because it was canceled.

You might also want to learn about how to properly check if the context failed due to a deadline: [How to check if an error is "deadline exceeded" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086405/how-to-check-if-an-error-is-deadline-exceeded-error)

Or if the context was canceled: [How to check if a request was cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179024/how-to-check-if-a-request-was-cancelled)