# How to check if an error is "deadline exceeded" error?

Tags: go

I'm sending a request with a context which specified with a 10 seconds timeout:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second * 10)
defer cancel()
_, err := client.SendRequest(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
```

now when I hit that timeout the error message is confusing:

> context deadline exceeded

Is it possible to check if the err is the timeout error so that I can print a nicer error message?

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second * 10)
defer cancel()
_, err := client.SendRequest(ctx)
if err != nil {
    if isTimeoutError(err) {
       return nil, fmt.Errorf("the request is timeout after 10 seconds") 
    }
    return nil, err
}
```

How to implement such `isTimeoutError` function?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this in Go 1.13+ is using the new [`errors.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) function.

```golang
// Create a context with a very short timeout
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Millisecond)
defer cancel()

// Create the request with it
r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com", nil)
r = r.WithContext(ctx)

// Do it, it will fail because the request will take longer than 1ms
_, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(r)
log.Println(err) // Get http://example.com: context deadline exceeded

// This prints false, because the http client wraps the context.DeadlineExceeded
// error into another one with extra information.
log.Println(err == context.DeadlineExceeded)

// This prints true, because errors.Is checks all the errors in the wrap chain,
// and returns true if any of them matches.
log.Println(errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can determine if an error is the result of a context timeout by comparing the error to [context.DeadlineExceeded](https://godoc.org/context#DeadlineExceeded):

```
 if err == context.DeadlineExceeded {
     // context deadline exceeded
 }
```

You can determine if an error is any timeout error using the following function:

```
func isTimeoutError(err error) bool {
     e, ok := err.(net.Error)
     return ok && e.Timeout()
}
```

This function returns true all timeout errors including the value `context.DeadlineExceeded`.  That value satisfies the `net.Error` interface and has a `Timeout` method that always returns `true`.

Comment: I did not know the 2nd fact (`context.DeadlineExceeded satisfies the net.Error interface`), but isn't a simple `err == context.DeadlineExceeded` enough? i.e. no need to check for interface match?

Comment: If you want to check for context timeout specifically, then use `err == context.DeadlineExceeded`.  If you want to check for all timeout errors including the context timeout, then use the `isTimeoutError` function shown in this answer.

Comment: Second function is so useful in case custom error type is derived from `context.DeadlineExceeded`, thanks.