# Hello, Im studying fyne.io for golang and I faced a problem

Tags: go, concurrency

Im studying fyne.io for golang and I faced a problem. I made a minimal dashboard interdace wuth tasks, that should start in concurency and the thing is that user must have rights to stop  any task anytime. I decided to use channel for sending task and context for stopping tasks, But that didnt work, I mean when task comes to channel, `worker(task *Task)`  starts and I click to stop and when that happens, `startTask(task *Task)` stops working, but `worker(task *Task)` doesnt stop. What is wrong? Am I doing something wrong?

[Exmaple running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4cev.jpg)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "github.com/k0kubun/pp"
    "time"
)

type Task struct {
    ID          int
    Chancel     context.CancelFunc
}

var channelTask chan *Task

func worker(task *Task)  {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i ++ {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Task ID: %d running...%d", task.ID, i))
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func startTask(task *Task) {
    go func() {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
        for {
            select {
            case <- ctx.Done():
                pp.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Task ID: %d stopped!", task.ID))
                return
            case task := <-channelTask:
                task.Chancel = cancel
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Task ID: %d stared!", task.ID))
                go func() {
                    worker(task)
                }()
            default:
                continue
            }
        }
    }()
}

func main()  {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Testing")
    channelTask = make(chan *Task)
    w.SetContent(createList())
    w.CenterOnScreen()
    w.Resize(fyne.Size{
        Width:  500,
        Height: 300,
    })
    w.SetFixedSize(true)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}

func createList() *widget.List {
    tasks := createTasks()
    return widget.NewList(
        func() int {
            return len(tasks)
        },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return container.NewGridWithColumns(3,
                widget.NewLabel(""),
                widget.NewButtonWithIcon("Run", theme.MediaPlayIcon(), func() {}),
                widget.NewButtonWithIcon("Stop", theme.MediaStopIcon(), func() {}),
            )
        },
        func(id widget.ListItemID, item fyne.CanvasObject) {
            task := tasks[id]
            item.(*fyne.Container).Objects[0].(*widget.Label).SetText(fmt.Sprintf("Task ID: %d", task.ID))
            buttonRun := item.(*fyne.Container).Objects[1].(*widget.Button)
            buttonStop := item.(*fyne.Container).Objects[2].(*widget.Button)
            buttonStop.Disable()
            buttonRun.OnTapped = func() {
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Task ID: %d Start button pushed.", task.ID))
                startTask(task)
                buttonRun.Disable()
                buttonStop.Enable()
                channelTask <- task
                return
            }
            buttonStop.OnTapped = func() {
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Task ID: %d Stop button pushed.", task.ID))
                task.Chancel()
                buttonRun.Enable()
                return
            }},
    )
}

func createTasks() []*Task {
    var tasks []*Task
    for i := 0; i < 5; i ++ {
        tasks = append(tasks, &Task{ID: i})
    }
    return tasks
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `worker` is not checking to see if the `Task` is cancelled.
I would suggest passing the `Context` in to the worker so you can see if it’s done.

Comment: if i pass context to worker and will check the cancellation, then my algorithm blocks the loop and will check the cancellation only after the algorithm is executed. And I need to stop the algorithm at my request.

- https://prnt.sc/1112b63

Comment: You should not move the wait code into the worker, that will block. Instead use the context to ask, perhaps each iteration, whether it was cancelled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179024/how-to-check-if-a-request-was-cancelled

Comment: Oh, I understand you. This actually worked for me - [link](https://prnt.sc/111g8b5). But the question still remains. If I have a long algorithm [link](https://prnt.sc/111g9p9), will I have to check it in every logical block for undo? I really can't interrupt the whole function with one stroke?

anyway, thank you!

Comment: I am not aware of any way that you can "just interrupt" code in a general sense. Any code that can be cancelled will need to handle that itself so that exiting is done cleanly.